# How to interpret a GEF diagram?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

Suppose user has drawn a standard flowchart using a GEF digram. Now via code we want to understand what diagrams are drawn in what order. I want to know is it possible to do that? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use GEF with MVC pattern, you create and modify a Model which results in drawing the View. You can then query the Model for the things you want.
The learning curve is quite steep, however.

Alternatively you can use the [Sirius project](https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/) to model your graph type and generate it all for you.